# Validating products in cart during checkout

Tags: woocommerce

For each products, I have specific shipping class added. So after the user adds some products to his/her cart and proceeds to checkout, I want to do a looping of the products in the cart to check it's shipping class and prevent the checkout if all the products belongs to a particular shipping class.

Any ideas on where to do the looping? I mean which action/hook I should modify?

**EDIT**

I tried the following hooks with the modified code of Rohil that he has provided as answer. But only once it works:

- woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review
- woocommerce_review_order_before_submit

I mean, I want the validation to be performed after the shipping details is entered and user presses the "PLACE ORDER" button. So at first it validates and displays the notice. But if press the PLACE ORDER button again without making any changes, the order would be placed!

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for ?

Add following code to a [new WordPress plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) or to a [site-specific snippets plugin](http://ottopress.com/2011/creating-a-site-specific-snippets-plugin/):

```
add_action('woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'validate_all_cart_contents');

function validate_all_cart_contents(){
    foreach ( WC()->cart->cart_contents as $cart_content_product ) {

        $shipping_class = $cart_content_product['data']->get_shipping_class();
        if($shipping_class == 'your_shipping_class_name'):
            return true;
        else:
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>You need to purchase products from the same shipping class</strong>' ), 'error' );
        endif;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have doubt.

Comment: Thank you. It works great. But can I ask you what would be the `action` to be modified, if I want to do this validation after the user enters the shipping address? I mean I want to do the validation after the user enters the shipping address. So during the validation, the country that the user entered for the shipping address would also be fetched and would be checked along with the class name. Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind. Found it : `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review`

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner while functions.php is probably the *easiest* place to dump some code, it isn't really ideal. Functions.php should be them/appearance specific and something like this should be it's own plugin.

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the product within that loop? I tried this but it's empty: `$cart_content_product['data']->post_title`

Comment: @VppMan you can check out what is it having by `var_dump($cart_content_product);`

Comment: @helgatheviking Thanks for pointing out.I was giving quick solution or you can say pointing him in right direction but **thank you** for giving  note. It would be more nice if you modify the answer :)

Comment: I want the validation to be performed after the shipping details is entered and user presses the "PLACE ORDER" button. I mean after the shipping details is entered. I tried `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review`. But it seems to be working for once. I mean after it shows the error messages and if I don't make any changes on the shipping/billing address, and presses the PLACE ORDER button, it would take me to the order success page!

Comment: What I can suggest you is to disable Place Order if Notice is there ..
I am not sure but as per my experience if any notice is there, woocommerce won't allow user to place order by default. But don't know why is it not working for you.

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner I agree that functions.php is one of the easiest places to test new code. Answer is updated.